# Flexbox items equal width except for last row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have photos with text underneath that is variable length. I'm using flexbox to have them align properly and using flex-grow to set the width so that they're equal. This works great for rows that wrap but the last line can stretches to fit the whole row.

How can I equally space each row and also have it start from the left?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uoc9j9pc/7/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="https://placeholder.com">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    <p>
     Brian
    </p>
  </a>
  <a href="https://placeholder.com">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
   <p>
    Betsy 
   </p>
  </a>
  <a href="https://placeholder.com">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
   <p>
    Variable Length Names Go Here 
   </p>
  </a>
  <a href="https://placeholder.com">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
   <p>
    Alan 
   </p>
  </a>
  <a href="https://placeholder.com">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
   <p>
    Another variable length 
   </p>
  </a>
<a href="https://placeholder.com">
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
   <p>
    Another variable length 
   </p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use css grids instead of flex! (if you can afford less browser support https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid)

Comment: @RMo this is unrelated to the problem he is facing

Comment: @Ahmad Alfy Why is that? What I understand from the question is that he is trying to place the elements in a way grids do by default.